# Platform specific code in Xamarin.Forms Prism

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a custom control and I need to use platform specific code inside it. I register platform specific implementation in `IPlatformInitializer`s on each platform. And I'm able to resolve instance via `IUnityContainer`. But I haven't reference to unity container inside my custom control. What is the designed approach by framework developers to resolve registered instance inside my custom control? I create my control in `XAML`.

With `Xamarin.Forms`'s approach I'm able to do:

```
DependencyService.Get<ISomeManager>();
```

from any place of an application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement a service locator pattern in order to access the container in your custom control.  You can cast the Application.Current to a PrismApplication and use the Container property off of it, or expose a new static property for the container.